# NSData type for Java?

Tags: java, client-server, nsdata, file-sharing

I am curious to know if there is anything like the [Cocoa NSData Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on Java. I have looked around but I can't find anything. I want to make a file sharing client server application.

Comment: Can you provide a link or explain what is this "NSData" type you mention?

Comment: Please have a look at the apple [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ByteBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)?

Comment: This is correct, but you can also use LONG as representation.

Comment: How so? A `long` can only store 8 bytes. But not really, because it is a signed value.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but would `byte[]` suffice?

Comment: I pretty much need this for get images from an iPhone client which sends image as NSData..

Answer (score 0):

Try an ArrayList<Byte>. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Yikes. Every `byte` would need to be wrapped in a `Byte` instance, and unwrapped on each access. A simple `byte[]` array would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

A simple byte[] can not be resized. There are some cases where additional data may be needed to inject at the end of byte[] so in that case you have to fully create a new byte[] array each time a modification is needed to sent which is rather a performance issue also.

ArrayList is flexible. You create once and can send additional data by injecting at the end of ArrayList, as well as no need to recreated the ArrayList to modify bytes.